# Deploying Web Service in JBoss using JAX-WS RI

Tags: deployment, jboss, jax-ws

I am trying to deploy a Web Service in JBoss 5 AS, without using the JBossWS which is the Red Hat's implementation of jsr-224. Thus, I am deploying my services in a .war file that already contains the JAX-WS Reference Implementation.

When I try to deploy the service without shipping the JAX-WS RI in my .war, it just deploys without issues just by mapping my services in the web.xml file. However, if I ship the JAX-WS RI .jar in my .war, the server does not deploy the service, and if I try to invoke it, I get a:

`Class is not a Servlet`

error. How can I deploy a service in JBoss without relying on the JBoss' implementation of jsr-224 but using my own implementation?

Comment: The answer is "yes". But with the info you've given us, that's the best answer I can give you.

Comment: What else do you need to know? I need to know how can I make my services use a different implementation of JAX-WS to the one shipped with JBoss (JBossWS). Edited: I am using JBoss 6.

Answer (score 0):

JBossWS supports pluggable WS implementations.
There are currenly avaliable Native, CXF or Metro.
Implementation can be changed by properly installing chosen flavor of JBossWS. 
Just adding jars won't help.

JAX-WS RI and Metro are basicly the same thing.
So you have to install jbossws-metro.

Istallation guide (slightly outdated but should give the hint):

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-Installation

Version compatibility matrix:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-SupportedTargetContainers

See also [Web service works on Tomcat 6 but not on JBoss AS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404628/web-service-works-on-tomcat-6-but-not-on-jboss-as-6/8444311#8444311).