# Web service works on Tomcat 6 but not on JBoss AS 6

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss

I autogenerated a SOAP webservice client from a WSDL (I use JAVA 1.6), and it works fine on Tomcat 6. However, when I put the client in a war and try to deploy it in JBoss Application Server 6.1 I get the following errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.common.Util.isJTAAvailable(Util.java:71) [:1.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.PipelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$WsitPipelineAssembler.isTransactionsEnabled(PipelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:468) [:1.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.PipelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$WsitPipelineAssembler.createClient(PipelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:271) [:1.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TubelineAssemblerFactory$TubelineAssemblerAdapter.createClient(TubelineAssemblerFactory.java:136) [:1.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createPipeline(WSServiceDelegate.java:423) [:1.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:589) [:1.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:329) [:1.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:311) [:1.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:304) [:1.0]
    **at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92) [:1.0.0.Final]**
    at com.ewave.meuhedet.ws.iclient.city.EWCITYServicesService.getEWCITYServices(EWCITYServicesService.java:74) [:]
    at com.ewave.meuhedet.ws.iclient.impl.PharmacyServiceIClientImpl.<init>(PharmacyServiceIClientImpl.java:58) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [:1.6.0_26]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126) [:3.0.1.RELEASE-A]
    ... 105 more
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImple cannot be cast to javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry**
    at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.common.TransactionManagerImpl.<init>(TransactionManagerImpl.java:106) [:1.0]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.common.TransactionManagerImpl.<clinit>(TransactionManagerImpl.java:62) [:1.0]
    ... 122 more
```

this is the autogenerated  getEWCITYServices function

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "EW_CITYServices")
    public EWCITYServices getEWCITYServices() {
        return super.**getPort**(new QName("http://ew_city.wsbeans.iseries",
                "EW_CITYServices"), EWCITYServices.class);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps a different version of a library or a missing library? Maybe that's why the casting attempt from arjuna stuff to javax.

Comment: thats a probable direction... but i dont know how to fix this cast problem, all I know is that arjunacore pacage is part of jboss 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you would have to stick with WS implementation supported by JBoss (Native, CXF or Metro).

Try just removing from classpath all jars containing sun's implementation (com.sun.xml.ws.*, etc). It's pretty old anyway and was superseded by Metro.

See http://www.jboss.org/jbossws.